# Scala and diamond inheritance when using traits

Tags: scala, diamond-problem

Given traits:

```
trait HasSize {
  def size() : Int
}

trait StorageTrait extends HasSize {
  def something() : Unit
}

trait YetAnotherStorageTrait extends HasSize {
  def anotherSomething() : Unit
}
```

I want to create class

```
class InMemoryStorage extends StorageTrait with YetAnotherStorageTrait {
   //...
}
```

now, method **size** of StorageTrait returns different thing than method YetAnotherStorageTrait (it's still a size, but of different collections).

What is the correct way to design such case in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a class which inherits traits which respond differently to the `size` method? Then there is no way to resolve this ambiguity than to use composition instead of mixin.

```
class InMemoryStorage
  def mainStorage: StorageTrait
  def auxStorage: YetAnotherStorageTrait

  def mainSize = mainStorage.size
  def auxSize  = auxStorage.size
}
```

Is that what you are looking after?

Comment: not really, I am looking for a way to "bind" a method implementation to trait. So whenever the class is accessed through StorageTrait, one "size" is used, and if it's accessed through "YesAnotherStorageTrait" - another implementation is used. I'm ready to pay the penalty when it's not possible to call "size" on instance of InMemoryStorage type, because it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That's not possible, you cannot "overload" a method with the same signature. If you mix-in both, you'll have to declare which one overrides the `size` method. If you want them to behave independently, you need to use a private size method; that still leaves the public size method ambiguous, so you should really not do this. What is the problem with the composition above -- if you call into `mainStorage`, that will correctly use its size, and for `auxStorage` that's true, too?

Comment: Just stumbled [across this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836060/cant-extend-two-traits-that-have-a-method-with-the-same-signature/1838214#1838214); although I still think composition is better, this may show you another possibility.