# Force Scala trait to implement a certain method

Tags: scala, mixins, traits

Is there a way to specify that a trait has to provide a concrete implementation of a method?

Given some mixin

```
class A extends B with C {
  foo()
}
```

The program will compile if either of `A`, `B`, or `C` implements `foo()`. But how can we force, for example, `B` to contain `foo`'s implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
class A extends B with C {
  super[B].foo()
}
```

This will only compile if `B` *implements* `foo`. Use with caution though as it (potentially) introduces some unintuitive coupling. Further, if `A` overrides `foo`, still `B`'s `foo` will be called.

One IMHO valid use case is [conflict resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836060/cant-extend-two-traits-that-have-a-method-with-the-same-signature):

```
trait B { def foo() = println("B") }
trait C { def foo() = println("C") }
class A extends B with C {
  override def foo() = super[B].foo()
}
```

If you want to make sure `B` *declares* `foo`, you can use type ascription:

```
class A extends B with C {
  (this:B).foo()
}
```

This will only compile if `B` *declares* `foo` (but it might be implemented in `C` or `A`).