# Force trait to implement method

Tags: scala, abstract, traits, concrete

I have a trait `I` (intermediary), a class `M` (mixer) mixing in the trait and a trait `S` (specific).

```
class M extends Something with S {
    def baz() = foo()
}

trait I {
    def foo(): { ...; bar(); ... }
    def bar()
}

trait S extends I {
    def bar() = 42
}
```

`I` serves as an intermediate layer between `M` and `S`, providing a common interface.

I have an implemented method `foo` in `I` that calls a method `bar` (not implemented in `I` but defined there). What I would like to achieve is that all traits extending `I` **must** implement `bar`, so that this would throw a compile time error because `bar` is not implemented:

```
trait Z extends I
```

Is this possible in Scala?

P.S.: I am aware of the answer of [Force Scala trait to implement a certain method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846085/force-scala-trait-to-implement-a-certain-method) but I do not want that kind of explicit coupling.

Comment: You can't force a `trait` to implement something like that.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need that? You'll get your compile error as soon as you try to have a concrete implementation of I (forcing you to provide a def bar). But a trait is by essence abstract...

Comment: I need it because the traits and the concrete implementation live in separate software packages. The traits are in a library that has no concrete usages of these traits. I could test for the correct implementation of these traits in my test suite. I would like it better, however, if the errors would already pop up at compile time (e.g. in my IDE).

Answer (score 1):

I thought about structural subtyping:

```
trait I[T<: { def:foo:Unit}]
```

....

would that work for you?

Comment: Is this what you have in mind?

    `class M extends Object with S {
        def baz() = foo()
    }

    trait I[T <: { def bar(): Unit }] {
        def foo() { bar() }
        def bar()
    }

    trait S extends I[S] {
        def bar() = 42
    }`

Because if so, then something like

    `trait Q extends I[Q] { }`

still does not throw a compile time error.

Comment: yeah I thought sth like that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a use case for self types :

```
trait Z {
   self : I =>
}
```

The compiler will check that any class in a hierarchy including `Z` is or extends `I`.

Comment: Could you please add an example? I don't see how I get compile time errors out of it if `trait Z` does not define `bar()`.

Comment: I think with self types it is still not possible to force a **trait** to implement a certain method. The compiler will throw an error if a **class** uses `trait Z` and `Z` did not provide an implementation. But as I said in a [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513843/force-trait-to-implement-method#comment28960874_19513843), I would like to catch the error earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way in Scala to force a trait to have concrete implementations for all methods.  You could write a macro that generated a small test class and then the compiler would verify that the test class was concrete.  It shouldn't be too hard to write a macro that takes this code:

```
@VerifyAllMethodsConcrete
trait Z extends I { ... }
```

and transforms it into this code:

```
trait Z extends I { ... }
class TestClassForVerifyingConcreteMethodsOfZ { }
```

Now if trait `Z` does not override `bar()` there will be an early error that says `TestClassForVerifyingConcreteMethodsOfZ needs to be abstract`.  This error message isn't perfectly clear but hopefully this does the early verification on `Z` that you want.